# Finding a node with or without further relations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Imagine a node (t) which can have a relation to another node (q) - but this is not necessarily given. A query needs to be made that finds all nodes (t) with specific properties in either cases no matter if I look for a property of (t) or (q). This shall work when there is a relation between (t) and (q) or also when there is no relationship but only a query parameter for (t).

I was trying to solve this with an optional match but couldnt figure it out:

```
MATCH (q) -- (t)
where q.property1 = 1 OR q.property2 = 2 // in case a search parameter for q has been given
OPTIONAL MATCH (t)
where t.property1 = 3 // in case the search looks for a node (t)
RETURN t
```

In the correct setup I should get a return of (t) when I look for a property of a related node (q) or a direct property of (t).

How would I change the query to get it working?
Thanks for your support

Comment: Why does it need to be a single Cypher query? Can't you just have a different query for each use case?

Comment: apoc has implemeted an if else statement in cypher. Check out the docs https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index31.html#_conditional_cypher_execution

Comment: Hi Sam, I am trying to implement a one-field-search for this task so the idea was to have one query which takes every information and runs through nodes that might have related data. I can of course split and try to fire two statements and combine the results - was just hoping I could have one query only.